# Calculate alphanumeric string to an integer in Excel

Tags: string, excel, time, excel-formula, vba

I have an issue that I've not been able to figure out even with many of the ideas presented in other posts.  My data comes in Excel and here are examples of each manner that any given cell might have the data:

```
4days 4hrs 41mins 29seconds
23hrs 43mins 4seconds
2hrs 2mins 
52mins 16seconds
```

The end result would be to calculate the total minutes while allowing seconds to be ignored, so that the previous values would end up as follows:

```
6041
52
1423
122
```

Would anyone have an idea how to go about that?

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: You'll have to parse the string values, retrieve any days, hours, and minutes, and do the calculations. You could do that with a VBA function pretty easily. The math itself is simple: (days * (24 * 60)) + (hours * 60) + minutes. You could split the string into an array based on spaces to retrieve individual chunks, pull out the numbers, and decide which calculation to do based on the remaining text in that chunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit tedious (and assumes units are always plural - also produces results in different order to example) but, with formulae only, if your data is in column A, in B1 and copied down:

```
="="&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"days","*1440+"),"hrs","*60+"),"mins","*1+"),"seconds","*0")," ","")&0
```

then Copy B and Paste Special values into C and apply Text to Columns to C with Tab as the delimiter.

Comment: Very interesting method.  I like that.

Comment: That may be, but I learned something from yours that might come in handy in the future.  And that's why I hang around.

Answer (score 1):

This **array formula**** should also work:

=SUM(IFERROR(0+MID(REPT(" ",31)&SUBSTITUTE(A1&"dayhrminsecond"," ",REPT(" ",31)),FIND({"day","hr","min","second"},REPT(" ",31)&SUBSTITUTE(A1&"dayhrminsecond"," ",REPT(" ",31)))-31,31),0)*{1440,60,1,0})

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is probably VBA with a regular expression. You can then easily find each of the fields, and do the maths.

If you want to stick to "pure" Excel, then it seems to only option is to use `SEARCH` or `FIND` to find the position of each of the "days", "hrs", "mins" in the text (you may have to check if they're always plural). Then use `MID` with the position found above to extract the different components. See http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/split-text-among-columns-by-using-functions-HA010102341.aspx for similar examples.

But there's quite a bit of work to handle the cases where some components are missing, so either you'll use quite a few cells, so you'll get a very complex formula...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a User Defined Function, written in VBA, which takes your string as the argument and returns the number of minutes.  Only the first characters of the time interval names are checked (e.g. d, h, m)  as this seems to provide sufficient discrimination.

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF),  opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like

=SumMinutes(A1)

in some cell.

```
Option Explicit
Function SumMinutes(S As String) As Long
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Dim lMins As Long
    Dim I As Long

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "(\d+)(?=\s*d)|(\d+)(?=\s*h)|(\d+)(?=\s*m)"
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        For I = 0 To MC.Count - 1
            With MC(I)
            lMins = lMins + _
                    .submatches(0) * 1440 + _
                    .submatches(1) * 60 + _
                    .submatches(2)
            End With
        Next I
    End If
End With

SumMinutes = lMins

End Function
```